# Flutter: fetch data with http.get

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm developing an app that read data with http.request method. All works fine if the device is online, but if the device is offline it goes out of my function.

My code is similar to this:

```
_fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://myUrl.com');
  //if the device is offline it jumps all the code below
  print("Hi"); //not printed
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     //do something
  } else {
     throw Exception('Failed to load'); //not throwed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
final response = await http.get('https://myUrl.com');
```

will throw an exception if it fails.

In your code, it assumes that the response succeeds and returns a http status code. **The status code can only tell you when the http server has an error, not when the connection has an error.** E.g. Having 404 status code means the http server couldn't find what you were looking for, but that **does** mean the connection was established.

If you look at your flutter console you will probably find the exception along the line of `unable to resolve host`, which is valid considering your device does not have internet access.

Since that line throws an uncaught exception, its logical that the rest of the method isn't executed. You should probably wrap it in a try catch clause to handle instances where the device is offline.